# How can limit the values per day to 1000

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, tableau-api, greatest-n-per-group

I have the query :

```
select A.*, A.DocumentID.DocId, D.Key, D.Value
from `serv.dam.events` A  
left join unnest (A.metadata) D 
where A.Creationtimestamp > '2018-10-01' 
order by Creationtimestamp desc 
limit 10000
```

I want to limit the values per day to 10000. How can i do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows:

```
select *
from (select e.*, e.DocumentID.DocId, D.Key, D.Value,
             row_number() over (partition by date(a.creationtimestamp) order by rand()) as seqnum
      from `serv.dam.events` e left join
           unnest (A.metadata) D 
      where A.Creationtimestamp > '2018-10-01' 
     ) e
where seqnum <= 1000
order by Creationtimestamp desc
```